# Moving fluid from one vertex of a triangle to another using windmills/spinners

Tags: fluid-dynamics, electric-current

I want to move fluid from point A to point E. Points B, C, and D are all "windmills" / spinners. Which directions (clockwise, counter-clockwise) should each windmill spin to provide maximum fluid flow?

Assume the fluid lies in an infinite bath. I.e., there is no default fluid flow.

[image]

Alternate: What if E lied halfway between B and C in the y direction? (shifted upwards slightly).

Comment: Probably they should turn in the direction of an arrow drawn from A to E.

Comment: So B is counterclockwise,  D is clockwise, and C is what? Or would there be more fluid if they were all clockwise?

Comment: C is clockwise, the path passes "above" (page orientation) C. Thus the push water along the path from A to E